# LoadShader Identifier not Found

Tags: c++, opengl-es

this is my code so far(i write it from book(OpenGl Es 2.0 Programming Guide)):
i used precompiled Header name "pch.h"

```
#include"Pch.h"
typedef struct
{
    GLuint programData;
}UserData;
void Render(ESContext* escontex);
int init(ESContext *escontex);
int main()
{
    ESContext escontext;
    UserData userData;
    esInitContext(&escontext);
    escontext.userData = &userData;
    esCreateWindow(&escontext, L"Hello World!", 800, 600, ES_WINDOW_RGB);
    esRegisterDrawFunc(&escontext, Render);
    esMainLoop(&escontext);


}
int init(ESContext*escontex)
{
    UserData *userData;
    const char vShaderStr[] =
        "attribute vec4 vPosition; \n"
        "void main() \n"
        "{ \n"
        " gl_Position = vPosition; \n"
        "} \n";
    const char fShaderStr[] =
        "precision meniump float; \n"
        "void main() \n"
        "{ \n"
        "gl_FragColor(1.0,0.0.1.0.1.0); \n"
        "}; \n";
    GLuint programObject;
    GLuint vertexShader;
    GLuint fragmentShader;
    vertexShader = LoadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER,  vShaderStr);
    fragmentShader = LoadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fShaderStr);

    programObject = glCreateProgram();
    if (programObject == 0) return 0;
    glAttachShader(programObject, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(programObject, fragmentShader);
    glBindAttribLocation(programObject, 0, "vPosition");
    glLinkProgram(programObject);
    userData->programData = programObject;
    glUseProgram(userData->programData);

}
GLuint LoadShader(GLenum type, const char* shaderSrc)
{
    GLuint shader;
    GLint compile;
    shader = glCreateShader(type);
    if (shader == 0) return 0;
    glShaderSource(shader,1 , &shaderSrc, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&compile);
    return shader;
}
void Render(ESContext* escontex)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, escontex->width, escontex->height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLfloat vVertices[] = { 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f };
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    eglSwapBuffers(escontex->eglDisplay, escontex->eglSurface);
}
```

my problem is when i compile this i get error:"LoadShader Identifier not Found!"
what is the problem?

and for the second question is there anything wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `LoadShader()` before it is defined. To fix the issue put a function declaration at the top of your file.

```
#include"Pch.h"
typedef struct
{
    GLuint programData;
}UserData;

void Render(ESContext* escontex);
int init(ESContext *escontex);
// this line here is new
GLuint LoadShader(GLenum type, const char* shaderSrc);

int main()
{
    ESContext escontext;
    ...
```